# Widget in IOS app development

Tags: widget

Hi I am new in mobile app development. I want to know that can we built widget for iPhone,like android? And can it be linked to any app which is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not support widgets (current limitation(, Apple only allows you to create apps.